# use of intel mkl in distributed system

Tags: distributed-system, intel-mkl

Let's say I have a distributed system, which has 36 nodes and each node has 36 cores, now I am using intel's dgemm function for multiplication and I want to use all the cores(36*36), How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Intel oneMKL uses all the available cores if you are running on multicore CPU. By setting MKL_VERBOSE=1 you can see the information which tells us how many cores are being utilized.
We have an option -qmkl=cluster that tells the compiler(intel compiler) to link using the cluster-specific libraries and the sequential libraries in oneMKL.
Please check the below link for more details.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-linux-developer-guide/top/working-with-onemkl-cluster-software/examples-of-linking-for-clusters/examples-for-linking-a-c-application.html